# Assign array items to individual variables on one line

Tags: php

I have a chunk of code like:

```
<?php
$person = array("John", "Smith", "Male", "Green");
$firstN = $person[0];
$lastN = $person[1];
$gender = $person[2];
$favColor = $person[3];
?>
```

I saw some code once that consolidated this, but I can't figure out how it was done, and can't find the page where I saw the example. It was something like:

```
<?php
$person = array("John", "Smith", "Male", "Green");
someFunction($firstN, $lastN, $gender,$favColor) = $person;
?>
```

It assigned the variables based on the values in the array in the same way the first example did it.

What could `someFunction` be in the above example?

Comment: `list($firstN, $lastN, $gender,$favColor) = $person;` its `list`

Comment: Another method would be [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for PHP's [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function.

Ex:

```
$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');
// Listing all the variables
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
```

In your case:

```
$person = array("John", "Smith", "Male", "Green");
list($firstN, $lastN, $gender,$favColor) = $person;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why yes! There's actually a cool way to do that:

```
list($firstN, $lastN, $gender, $favColor) = $person;
```

And that's it! All the variables would be populated.

See **[`list()` PHP manual entry](http://php.net/list)**.